# I'm trying to calculate and return the user change and I don't know how

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, return, calculator

I'm newbie in programming and I need to do a final project.
I can calculate and return the user change.
I tried with the for loop but and it will calculate just the first product from the list.

```
public class ChangeCalculator{
    public double moneyInserted;
    
    
    ChangeCalculator(double moneyInserted){
        
    }

public static void dispence (double moneyInserted) {
  for(Product product: Product.values()) {
      if(moneyInserted >= product.getPrice()){
            System.out.println("Vending");
            double changeReturn = (double)moneyInserted - (double)product.getPrice();
            System.out.println("    ");
            System.out.println("Here is your $" +changeReturn+" in change");
            System.out.println("Thank You");
            break;
        }
      else {
          System.out.println("Unsuffient funds");
      }
      break;
}
  
}
}
```

Comment: There's no `return` in your method, you are not returning anything (and it is defined as `void`, meaning it doesn't return anything). `break` stops the loop (and you unconditionally break out of your loop as the last statement, effectively turning your `for` loop into an `if` conditional.

Comment: Is the intention to vend the first product found that the customer has enough money to pay for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you put those break statements.
A `break` will break the loop, that's why you're not getting past the first item. Drop the breaks and it should work.

```
for(Product product: Product.values()) {
  if(moneyInserted >= product.getPrice()){
        System.out.println("Vending");
        double changeReturn = (double)moneyInserted - (double)product.getPrice();
        System.out.println("    ");
        System.out.println("Here is your $" +changeReturn+" in change");
        System.out.println("Thank You");
        break; // this will end the loop the first time you return change
    }
  else {
      System.out.println("Unsuffient funds");
  }
  break; // this will end the loop after the first product, regardless of the outcome
}
```

Comment: I'm traying to subtract the moneyInserted by the user with the price of the product that the user  chose. but the price variable of the product is private. I dont know how to use it in the ChangeCalculator class, the only way was using the for loop

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify the problem. The problem is not the loop but the break.